# Apache Spark - run extermal exe or jar file parallel

Tags: java, parallel-processing, apache-spark

I have .exe file (I don't have source files so I won't be able to edit the program) taking as parameter path to file which be processing and on the end giving results. For example in console I run this program as follow : `program.exe -file file_to_process [other_parametrs]`. I have also jar executable file which take two parameters `file_to_process` and second file and `[others_parameters]`. In both cases I would like to split input file into smallest part and run programs in parallel. Is there any way to do it efficient with Apache Spark Java framework. I'm new with parallel computations and I read about RDD and pipe operator but I don't know if it would be good in my case because I have path to file.

I will be very grateful for some help or tips.

Comment: IMHO, Spark might be overkill and slow unless you have a cluster at hand. If by parallel computation you mean using all cores of a single machine, I would just partition manually and launch multiple processes. But overall, there is no way to answer your question as-is. There are too many "depends": kind of input, how can it be partitioned, size, cluster availability and size, memory requirements, kind of algorithm, etc.

Comment: For testing I will be using local machine but in the future I would like to use Amazon EC2 cloud with cluster on it. In the file I have independent part of data which can be processing separately. The problem is that file can be very big and the computation last too long even on local machine with multiple cores. Is there any way to split the file and run it in parallel by giving the different path to each file.

Comment: Farming out executable jobs to a cluster seems like a job for a queuing system like Sun Grid Engine (SGE) and its descendants. Amazon created [CfnCluster](http://cfncluster.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) to manage such system on their cloud.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into similar issues recently, and I have a working code with spark 2.1.0. The basic idea is that, you put your exe with its dependencies such as dll into HDFS or your local and use [addFiles](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#addFile(java.lang.String)) to add them into driver, which will also copy them into work executors. Then you can load your file as a RDD, and use mapPartitionsWithIndex function to save each partition into local and execute the exe (use SparkFiles.get to get the path from the work executor) to that partition using [Process](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-to-execute-external-system-commands-in-scala).
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I think the general answer is "no". Spark is a framework and in general it administers very specific mechanisms for cluster configuration, shuffling its own data, read big inputs (based on HDFS), monitoring task completion and retries and performing efficient computation. It is not well suited for a case where you have a program you can't touch and that expects a file from the local filesystem.

I guess you *could* put your inputs on HDFS, then, since Spark accepts arbitrary java/Scala code, you could use whatever language facilities you have to dump to a local file, launch a process (i.e.[this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)), then build some complex logic to monitor for completion (maybe based on the content of the output). the `mapPartitions()` Spark method would be the one best suited for this.

That said, I would not recommend it. It will be ugly, complex, require you to mess with permissions on the nodes and things like that and would not take good advantage of Spark's strengths.

Spark is well suited for you problem though, especially if each line of your file can be processed independently. I would look to see if there is a way to get the program's code, a library that does the same or if the algorithm is trivial enough to re-implement.

Probably not the answer you were looking for though :-(

Comment: Thanks a lot. Maybe You know answer how the JavaRDD<String> works with pipe method ? The file will be partition by default 64MB parts and after that it will be send every line to shell command or every line in partition as one part. It isn't possible that spark split line ? When I make JavaRDD<MyClass> every object will be sent to external process as byte Array ? I have to reimplement some method ?

Comment: Spark will use the kind of inputs as Hadoop. The default will not split lines. Check http://spark.apache.org/docs/1.2.0/programming-guide.html#external-datasets for some tips on how to read lines or objects. You don't need to reimplement methods, but can create your own InputTypes to read and write if you want to tweak serialization.

Comment: AFAIK, an entire partition will be piped to your program (so, many unbloken lines). Your program probably need to support piping (like grep for instance), and I don't get the feeling yours does. But at the end of the day, give it a try! Build a sample local project using the grep command first and go from there :-)